# Partial differentiation or normal differentiation

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

Consider the function
$$
f(x,y)
=
\begin{cases}\frac{xy(x^2-y^2)}{x^2+y^2}, & (x,y)\neq(0,0)\\
0, & \text{otherwise.}\end{cases}
$$

Compute $$\frac{d^2f}{dxdy}(0,0)$$ and $$\frac{d^2f}{dydx}(0,0).$$

Why does it not have the partial symbol? When it is a 'd', doesn't that mean it is one variable only?

Comment: I'd say the reason is laziness, $d$,$\partial$,$\delta$ are often used interchangeably, so don't let that bother you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should probably be $\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x\partial y}(0,0)$ and $\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial y\partial x}(0,0)$.
You should check your book (or other material or instructor) for notation conventions as they vary from source to source.
In some contexts derivatives with $d$, $\partial$ and $D$ mean the same thing, sometimes not.

For example, you could be asked to show that under suitable assumptions on a function $f:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R$ you have $\nabla f=Df$.
I can think of two meanings for such an exercise: the gradient is the same thing as the derivative as a linear approximation (if $Df$ happens to be defined so); or that the strong and weak gradients are the same thing.

Even though people use sloppy notation and you just have to live with it, you should always be *sure* that you know what the notation means exactly.